# Django query object property with comparison

Tags: python, django

I have a bunch of history objects in my db that I need to query to see if the minute on that date is between two minutes. I want to do something like this:

```
h = Thing.history.filter(
    Q(history_date__minute__lte=40) & Q(history_date__minute__gte=20),
    id=thing_id
)
```

But I get an error trying to do this:

```
FieldError: Unsupported lookup 'minute' for DateTimeField or join on the field not permitted.
```

How do I achieve this effect in Django?

Comment: is history_date__minute an `int` or `datetime` format

Comment: history_date is a datetime, history_date__minute is an int.

Comment: What version of Django are you using?

Comment: @ShangWang [minute is a field lookup for datetime fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#minute).

Comment: @PauloAlmeida: Ah that's good to know. But the doc also says: **For datetime fields, an exact minute match. Takes an integer between 0 and 59.** Sounds like `lte` and `gte` is not supported.

Comment: @ShangWang is right. `lte`, `gte` etc. are not yet supported in any release version. They are supported in the development version. See the last note in the [dev docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#minute).